# Customer Can't log in

Tags: customer, logging, ce-1.8.1.0

I just migrated my website. But I got a problem.

My customers can't log in to their account. When click log in on log-in page. http://www.mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/ It should be log in on their account but it redirects the same page.

I'm very new to magento.
Please Help me how to fix that?

Comment: Magento Version?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt 1.8.1 Sir

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do you have a custom template and did it work in 1.7? In 1.8.1 form_keys were added, so please check your custom template for this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

if it is missing, add it as in

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
```

And check all other forms after the update:

https://gist.github.com/drobinson/7913822

Comment: Dear sir, I don't have a custom template.I didn't touch the core file. And  <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>   is not missing. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please stop calling me sir :) And no, was the only idea I had :-(

Comment: this is the problem I described ;-) Great you fixed it!

Comment: Anyway, Thanks for your help. Really glad. :)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.blueclawsearch.co.uk/blog/2013/12/12/fix-customer-cannot-login-to-magento-1-8-1/  this is a solution for the problem

Here's what the above link has to say:

- Go to `template/customer/form/login.phtml` and `template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml` and under

  ```
  <ul class="form-list">
  ```
- Add the following code in the login form

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
  ```

If you are using the login form in different templates then you use add the `form_key` to the other parts as well.

Comment: Nothing but a link to a solution is not appropriate on Stack Exchange sites because it may encourage link spam.  Also, external links may change over time braking this 'solution'.  Please post the solution here and reference the source link after if you like.

Comment: As shaneveeg warned, the link is now broken, leaving the rest of us in [this state](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in 
/app/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

I made this changes and it began to work for me

```
/**
 * Login post action
 */
public function loginPostAction()
{

    // generate form_key if missing or invalid
    if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null))
            || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()) {
        $this->getRequest()->setParams(array(
            'form_key' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
        ));
    }
```