# Why is log in form on home page not actually logging in?

Tags: login

I'm using the existing form from the default login page and calling the action like this:

`<?php $custmlogin= new Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login();?> <form action="<?php echo $custmlogin->getPostActionUrl() ?>"...`

The action gets echoed just fine resulting in the same path I initially had hard coded, but it doesn't actually log me in. I just goes to the standard login page with a form for me to log in. Is there something else I need to do to actually submit the data and get logged in successfully?

Comment: Have you tried the solution at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11871/customer-cant-log-in

Comment: That didn't work either... same result using both methods. Just redirects to the default login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it using this:

`{{block type ="Mage_Customer_Block_Form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" }}`

Instead of pulling in my own custom block. Not really sure what the difference was until I looked at the source code and noticed there was a slight difference in the action attribute.

[mageUz's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14037/2870) answer was very close. So instead of this:

`<?=Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login', array('_secure' => true))?>`

it was:

`<?=Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginPost', array('_secure' => true))?>`

All it needed was **Post** added to it. Then I removed the Mage block and just kept mine in there.

Thank you guys for the help and putting me in the right direction.

Comment: I tried, but it said I have to wait till tomorrow. I will as soon as I can though.

Answer (score 1):

`Mage_Customer_AccountController` (`/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`) handles login functionality, use it's url:

```
<form action="<?=Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login', array('_secure' => true))?>">
```

Comment: thank you for the response.I tried it and it's just echoing the same path as I had before using the variable and hard coding it in. So I end up with the same result. It obviously echoed: customer/account/login and the getUrl just puts the domain in front of it. I've tried it multiple ways, but no luck :/